# How to go to a details page via routerLink on Ionic 4?

Tags: firebase, ionic4

I'm going (using `routerLink)` to a details page of an object, but instead of the `ID`, it appears `undefined`, and don't know how to do it correctly, this is my code:

Tab routing

```
{
    path: 'book/:id',
    loadChildren: '../book-detail/book-detail.module#BookDetailPageModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Page **A** (FROM):

```js
...
bookId = null
bookRef: AngularFirestoreDocument

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private af: AngularFirestore,
    private service: BookService
) { }
...
```

**HTML**

```html
<ion-card [routerLink]="['/book/', id]" routerDirection="forward">
```

---

Page **B** (TO):

```js
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.bookId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (this.bookId) {
        this.loadBook(this.bookId);
    }
}

loadBook(bookId) {
    this.af.collection<Book>('books')
        .doc<Book>(bookId)
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.book = data
        });
}
...
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=not-found]:
>   No document to update:
>   projects/books-29320f/databases/(default)/documents/books/undefined
>   FirebaseError: No document to update:
>   projects/books-29320f/databases/(default)/documents/books/undefined

On my url on my detailspage of the book it says: http://localhost:8100/book/undefined

UPDATED 2:

Book detail module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BookDetailPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [BookDetailPage]
})
export class BookDetailPageModule {}
```

Comment: Should be good to add `BookDetailPageModule` routing

Comment: Where? please be explicit

Comment: What I mean is you should add `BookDetailPageModule` content in your question, you are trying to navigate to `/book/:id` which is handled by `BookDetailPageModule` routing

Comment: To let you know... don't have any problem with the routes (I think so)... just cannot get ID it seems...

Comment: Yes not with the routes, but with the param `id` you are trying to send. Did you update the post ? I can't see the changes

Comment: Yes i did it, down you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY RESOLVED:

I didn't know about it's just to put this code:

```
<ion-card [routerLink]="['book/', book.id]" routerDirection="forward">
```

Instead of what I did (see on my question)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `:id` to `BookDetailPage` path in `BookDetailPageModule` :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: BookDetailPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [BookDetailPage]
})
export class BookDetailPageModule {}
```

Comment: Did it help you ?

Comment: Also it makes me dont go to the detail page... the problem is, the ID is undefined and i'm trying to get the ID :S